# Using jQuery to rearrange page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm relatively new to jQuery and JavaScript, and I think I understand what is causing my issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm using SimpleWeather.JS , moment.js, and moment.js timezone to get the current time and weather for 4 cities.  I have all the data I want on the page, but I want to move each city's time as the second paragraph in each city's div. Any ideas on how to get that working with my current code or is there a more efficient way of producing this result?

http://jsfiddle.net/ljd144/p6tpvz1r/

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.weather').each(function () {
        var city = $(this).attr("city");
        var woeid = $(this).attr("woeid");
        var degrees = $(this).attr("degrees");
        var continent = $(this).attr("continent");

        $.simpleWeather({
            zipcode: '',
            woeid: woeid,
            location: '',
            unit: degrees,
            success: function (weather) {

                if (continent == 'America'){
                    html = '<p>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</p>';
                }
                else {
                    html = '<p>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.country + '</p>';
                }
                //html += '<p class="time" id="'+city+'></p>';
                //html += '<p>' + weather.updated + '</p>';
                html += '<p><i class="icon-' + weather.code + '"></i> ' + weather.temp + '&deg;' + weather.units.temp + '<p>';
                html += '<p>' + weather.currently + '<p>';


                $('#weather_' + city).html(html);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $('#weather_' + city).html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
            }
        });
    });


     $(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('.time').each(function () {
                var city = $(this).attr("city");
                var continent = $(this).attr("continent");
                //$(this).text(city);
                var utc = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                var localTime = moment.utc(utc).toDate();
                cityTime = moment(localTime).tz(continent + "/" + city).format('ddd MMM D YYYY, h:mm:ss a z');
                $(this).text(city+ ': '+cityTime);
            });
        }, 1000);


    });

         $('.time').each(function () {
             var city = $(this).attr("city");
             //$('#weather_' + city).after(this);

         });  



});
```

Comment: your custom attribute should be prefix with data- to pass the w3c. Like data-city.

Comment: `$(function () {})` is a shortcut for`ready()`... So you've a ready  handler inside another `ready()` handler which is unnecessary...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto) method to append the time to the respective `<div>` having same city attribute using the [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector like:

```
 $(this).text(city + ': ' + cityTime).appendTo("div[city='"+city+"']");
```

### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6tpvz1r/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and help.  Is there anyway to easily make it appear right below the city, state/country line?

Comment: Thanks!  I was so stuck on how to get it positioned just where I wanted it.  Lots to learn!

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/p6tpvz1r/2/)

Change:

```
            $(this).text(city+ ': '+cityTime);
```

To:

```
            var timeP = $('p.time','#weather_' + city);
            timeP = timeP.length ? timeP : $('<p/>',{class:'time'}).appendTo( '#weather_' + city );
            timeP.text(cityTime);
```